# Gcloud Kubernetes and Redis memory store, intermittent issues, host not found

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-cloud-memorystore

From time to time once a week or so we get in a weird state with our Kubernetes cluster not able to connect to the memory store Redis service.

**K8S mater version**: 1.10.7
    cloud beta redis instances list --region europe-west1                              1 ↵  10122  12:26:38

```
INSTANCE_NAME   REGION        TIER         SIZE_GB  HOST       PORT  NETWORK  RESERVED_IP   STATUS  CREATE_TIME
chefclub-redis  europe-west1  STANDARD_HA  1        10.0.10.4  6379  default  10.0.10.0/29  READY   2018-05-29T14:12:46
```

Getting a No route to host.

```
kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox -- sh                                    ✓  10125  12:28:36
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # telnet 10.0.10.4 6379
telnet: can't connect to remote host (10.0.10.4): No route to host
```

It happened a few times in the past, Now I just did an upgrade of my node to `1.10.7` and everything went back in place, I could connect again.

I wonder what other steps I could take next it happens?

Comment: Does it happen from all kubernertes nodes?  Did you try connecting from the node that failed?   Not the pod. It's either some iptables rule on your node or some firewall rule on your node.

Comment: Will try that if it happens again, thank you @Rico

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed the instructions on how to [connect](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting_from_a_pod_running_a_bash_shell) to Redis instance from a cluster and [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/troubleshooting) doc. Note that while connecting to redis server if your cluster configuration have IP aliases enabled, [steps](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting_from_a_pod_running_a_bash_shell) may vary.

You can research through Stackdriver logging for Kubernetes pods and check for complete error message during the affected timeframe. This will help you check for known issues in Github or other Stackoverflow thread. [Advanced Stackdriver logging filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters#getting_started_with_advanced_filters) to view pod logs:

> resource.type="container" resource.labels.cluster_name="cluster_name"
>   resource.labels.namespace_id="k8s_namespace"
>   labels."container.googleapis.com/k8s_pod_name"="k8s_pod_name"

If you did not find any known issues and suspect that the issue could be on Google end. You can create an issue using the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).